# Storing List of objects using DataType.SERIALIZABLE in ormlite android

Tags: android, ormlite

How to save an ArrayList using ORMlite in android my model is as follows

```
class Model{
    @DatabaseField
    public String type = "";

    @DatabaseField
    public String name = "";

    @DatabaseField
    public Date dateTime = null;

    @DatabaseField
    ArrayList<Item> items = null;
}
```

And Item class has

```
class Item{
     @DatabaseField
     String itemName;
     ...
}
```

I am getting the following exception :

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORMLite can't store unknown class class
      java.util.ArrayList for field 'items'.   Serializable fields must specify
      dataType=DataType.SERIALIZABLE
```

But when i specify my field as

```
@DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.SERIALIZABLE)
ArrayList<Item> items = null;
```

The compiler gives a error called field cannot be resolved please help me with this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've just changed the error message to be:

> ORMLite does not know how to store class
>         java.util.ArrayList for field 'items'.  Use another class, custom persister, or to serialize it use dataType=DataType.SERIALIZABLE

Maybe that makes more sense?  [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) is trying to say that it doesn't know how to store lists in a field.  If you want to store collection of items then maybe you should take a look at the [foreign-collection documentation](http://ormlite.com/docs/foreign-collection).

Comment: This still does not make sense.  You say 'or to serialize it use dataType=DataType.SERIALIZABLE', which is what the user mentions he tries.  Do you mean to say that even if you use dataType=DataType.SERIALIZABLE on an ArrayList ORMLite cannot handle it?